# Why are my images not staying in place when the browser is adjusted?

Tags: html, image-scaling

I am a beginner at coding so any advice or help would be great. The main background image resizes with the browser but the other logos and graphic elements do not. How can I make the other images resize AND stay in place when the browser size changes?

Here is a link:

https://f0476ead42deb6e625581792b6fc55aec2b47ff7.googledrive.com/host/0B-QoEzNnMcBDanFlYm5hTDdZUVk

Comment: Please **edit your question** and add the relevant HTML and CSS to your question. Your link will become invalid in a few weeks or months and then your question will be useless to others since the context is lost.

Answer (score 0):

Use percentages, vw, vh, vmin, or vmax in in the positioning and sizing of your images. vw, scales with the width of the viewport, vh scales with the height of the viewport, vmin scales with the minimum of the width and height of the viewport and vmax scales with the maximum of the width and height of the viewport.This will make them scale with the size of the viewport. Percentages scale with the size of the containing block. For example (one of your images):

```
#secondharvest {
    position: absolute;
    left: 10vw;
    top: 10vw;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 15vw;
    height: 10vw;
}
```